# Comparar duas listas sem interferência de letras em maiúsculo e minúsculo

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Quero desenvolver um sistema de log-in onde não permite que usuários novos possuam os mesmos nomes já utilizados por outros usuários já cadastrados, mas estou tendo uma dificuldade em questão de letras maiúsculas e minúsculas quando comparo as listas. Como faço para deixar as duas listas com todas letras minúsculas?

```
current_users  = [ 'Hiquinho', 'pup', 'billy', 'jp', 'pichuto', 'schuh']
new_users = [ 'HIQUINHO', 'sara', 'Billy', 'amalia', 'lucca', 'Schuh']
if new_users:
    for new_user in new_users:
        if new_user.lower() in current_users:
            print('Nome ja em uso, forneça outro ID\n')
        elif new_user.lower() not in current_users:
            print('Seja bem vindo, somos muito gratos pelo seu login '
            + new_user.title() + '!\n')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando o nome do usuário é `'HIQUINHO'`, ao chamar `lower` ele se torna `hiquinho`, e você compara com os valores da outra lista, que só tem `'Hiquinho'`, por isso ele acha que este usuário ainda não foi utilizado.

Sendo assim, você deve comparar cada novo usuário com a versão em minúsculas dos usuários atuais:

```
current_users  = [ 'Hiquinho', 'pup', 'billy', 'jp', 'pichuto', 'schuh']
new_users = [ 'HIQUINHO', 'sara', 'Billy', 'amalia', 'lucca', 'Schuh']
current_users_lowercase = list(map(str.lower, current_users))

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user.lower() in current_users_lowercase:
        print(f'Nome {new_user} já em uso, forneça outro ID')
    else:
        print(f'Seja bem vindo, somos muito gratos pelo seu login {new_user.title()}!')
```

Veja também que não precisa testar se a lista `new_users` está vazia. Se estiver, ele nem entra no `for`, então o `if new_users:`  é redundante.

E a condição do `elif` também é redundante. Se o usuário está na lista, ele entra no `if`, e se não estiver, ele vai para o `else` (ou seja, não precisa testar de novo isso com `elif`, pode usar `else` direto).

A saída do código acima é:

```
Nome HIQUINHO já em uso, forneça outro ID
Seja bem vindo, somos muito gratos pelo seu login Sara!
Nome Billy já em uso, forneça outro ID
Seja bem vindo, somos muito gratos pelo seu login Amalia!
Seja bem vindo, somos muito gratos pelo seu login Lucca!
Nome Schuh já em uso, forneça outro ID
```

---

Vale lembrar que, dependendo dos caracteres que podem ter no nome do usuário, nem sempre `lower()` funciona. Por exemplo, o caractere alemão `ß` é equivalente a "ss", mas `lower()` não o altera. Para estes - e muitos outros - casos, a documentação recomenda o uso de [`casefold`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold):

```
print('ß'.lower()) # ß
print('ß'.casefold()) # ss
```

Ou seja, bastaria trocar para:

```
current_users  = [ 'Hiquinho', 'pup', 'billy', 'jp', 'pichuto', 'schuhss']
new_users = [ 'HIQUINHO', 'sara', 'Billy', 'amalia', 'lucca', 'Schuhß']

# usar casefold em vez de lower
current_users_lowercase = list(map(str.casefold, current_users))

for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user.casefold() in current_users_lowercase: # usar casefold em vez de lower
        print(f'Nome {new_user} já em uso, forneça outro ID')
    else:
        print(f'Seja bem vindo, somos muito gratos pelo seu login {new_user.title()}!')
```

Claro que se só tiver caracteres ASCII, usar `lower` é o suficiente.

Comment: muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Caso o objetivo seja apenas emitir a mensagem de saudação sem ter que fazer qualquer ação configuração adicional é possível utilizar uma abordagem mais funcional usando uma [expressão lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) aplicada com o [builtin map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) dentro de [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) cujo o texto a ser exibido seja decidido através de uma [expressão condicional](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

```
current_users  = [ 'Hiquinho', 'pup', 'billy', 'jp', 'pichuto', 'schuh']
new_users = [ 'HIQUINHO', 'sara', 'Billy', 'amalia', 'lucca', 'Schuh', 'User1']

#Converte cada elemento de current_users caixa alta e armazena no array users
users= [str.casefold(e) for e in current_users]

#Junta todos os log e os imprime separados por um \n
print("\n".join([      
    #Operador ternário se t[0] for true devolve a primeira frase senão devolve a outra.
    f'{str.title(t[1])} já está em uso, forneça outro ID.' 
    if t[0] else f'Seja bem vindo {str.title(t[1])}, obrigado pelo login!'
    #Para cada elemento e em new_users retorna a tupla t (str.casefold(e) in users, e).
    for t in map(lambda e : (str.casefold(e) in users, e), new_users) 
]))
```

Resultado:

```
Hiquinho ja em uso, forneça outro ID.
Seja bem vindo Sara, obrigado pelo login!
Billy ja em uso, forneça outro ID.
Seja bem vindo Amalia, obrigado pelo login!
Seja bem vindo Lucca, obrigado pelo login!
Schuh ja em uso, forneça outro ID.
Seja bem vindo User1, obrigado pelo login!
```

Teste o exemplo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/GrossPepperyDribbleware)

Caso o objetivo seja realizar uma ou mais ações dependo do resultado da verificação de que o elemento de `new_users` esteja ou não contido em `current_users` você pode usar um controle de fluxo mais imperativo usando [`for`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) e [`if`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements):

```
current_users  = [ 'Hiquinho', 'pup', 'billy', 'jp', 'pichuto', 'schuh']
new_users = [ 'HIQUINHO', 'sara', 'Billy', 'amalia', 'lucca', 'Schuh', 'User1']

#Converte cada elemento de current_users caixa alta e armazena no array users
users= [str.casefold(e) for e in current_users]

#Essa lista irá receber os nomes de usuário que estiver em new_users e 
# que não estejam em current_users.
trusted_users = []

#Para cada elemento e em new_users retorna a tupla t (str.casefold(e) in users, e).
for t in map(lambda e : (str.casefold(e) in users, e), new_users):
  #Verifica resultado da expressão str.casefold(e)...
  if t[0]: 
    #...se True o usuário já está em uso.
    print(f'{str.title(t[1])} já em uso, forneça outro ID.')
  else:
    #...se False o nome de usuário ainda não está em uso.
    trusted_users.append(t[1]) #... o adiciona a lista trusted_users.
    print(f'Seja bem vindo {str.title(t[1])}, obrigado pelo login!')

#Imprime a lista trusted_users.
print(f'\nNovos usuários verificados: {trusted_users}')
```

Resultado:

```
Hiquinho ja em uso, forneça outro ID.
Seja bem vindo Sara, obrigado pelo login!
Billy ja em uso, forneça outro ID.
Seja bem vindo Amalia, obrigado pelo login!
Seja bem vindo Lucca, obrigado pelo login!
Schuh ja em uso, forneça outro ID.
Seja bem vindo User1, obrigado pelo login!

Novos usuários verificados: ['sara', 'amalia', 'lucca', 'User1']
```

Teste o código no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LimeTriangularParallelalgorithm)

Comment: muito obrigado!